# Does __str__() call decode() method behind scenes?

Tags: python, django, string, unicode

It seems to me that built-in functions `__repr__` and `__str__` have an important difference in their base definition.

```
>>> t2 = u'\u0131\u015f\u0131k'
>>> print t2
ışık
>>> t2
Out[0]: u'\u0131\u015f\u0131k'
```

`t2.decode` raises an error since `t2` is a unicode string.

```
>>> enc = 'utf-8'
>>> t2.decode(enc)
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\java\python\Python25\Lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordin
al not in range(128)
```

`__str__` raises an error as if `decode()` function is being called:

```
>>> t2.__str__()
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordin
al not in range(128)
```

but `__repr__` works without problem:

```
>>> t2.__repr__()
Out[0]: "u'\\u0131\\u015f\\u0131k'"
```

Why does `__str__` produce an error whereas `__repr__` work properly?

This small difference seems to cause a bug in one django application that I am working on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, `__str__` can only output ascii strings. Since t2 contains unicode codepoints above ascii, it cannot be represented with just a string. `__repr__`, on the other hand, tries to output the python code needed to recreate the object. You'll see that the output from repr(t2) (this syntax is preferred to `t2.__repr_()`) is exactly what you set t2 equal to up on the first line. The result from repr looks roughly like ['\', 'u', '0', ...], which are all ascii values, but the output from str is trying to be [chr(0x0131), chr(0x015f), chr(0x0131), 'k'], most of which are above the range of characters acceptable in a python string. Generally, when dealing with django applications, you should use `__unicode__` for everything, and never touch `__str__`.

More info in [the django documentation on strings](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/str/).

Answer (score 5):

In general, calling `str.__unicode__()` or `unicode.__str__()` is a very bad idea, because bytes can't be safely converted to Unicode character points and vice versa. The exception is ASCII values, which are generally the same in all single-byte encodings. The problem is that you're using the wrong method for conversion.

To convert `unicode` to `str`, you should use `encode()`:

```
>>> t1 = u"\u0131\u015f\u0131k"
>>> t1.encode("utf-8")
'\xc4\xb1\xc5\x9f\xc4\xb1k'
```

To convert `str` to `unicode`, use `decode()`:

```
>>> t2 = '\xc4\xb1\xc5\x9f\xc4\xb1k'
>>> t2.decode("utf-8")
u'\u0131\u015f\u0131k'
```

Answer (score 2):

To add a bit of support to John's good answer:

To understand the naming of the two methods *encode()* and *decode()*, you just have to see that Python considers unicode strings of the form **u'...'** to be in the **reference format**. You *encode* going from the reference format into another format (e.g. utf-8), and you *decode* from some other format to come to the reference format. The unicode format is always considered the "real thing" :-).

Answer (score 0):

Note that in Python 3, unicode is the default, and `__str__()` should always give you unicode.